# Changing popover content according to current image

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

Hi I would like to change my popover content according to the current image displayed but it only displays the first image provided (a.jpg).I would like the popup img to change according to the current img src.

HTML:

```
<img id="popover" rel="popover" title="" data-content="" 
 data-trigger="hover" class="img-circle" 
 onmouseout="displaypreviousimage(this)" 
 onmouseover="displaynextimage(this)" 
 src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DOSczbmX4AAiFEd.jpg" 
 width="300px"/>
```

Javascript:

```
var images = [
        "https://img00.deviantart.net/e568/i/2013/177/b/2/hatsune_miku___last_night_good_night_by_vocalmaker-d6as4aq.png", 
        "https://i.scdn.co/image/e331fd3822f9691fbd707fb3e393bafd5fcf4b8a",
        "https://germankpopinfo.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/bts-wings-album-cover.jpg"
    ];

var counter = 0;

function displaynextimage(x){
    var imghtml = "";
    if( counter < images.length)
    {
        x.src = images[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        counter = 0;
        x.src = images[counter];
    }
    if(x.src == images[0])
    {
        imghtml = '<img src="a.jpg" width="150px">';
        $('#popover').popover({placement: 'right', content: imghtml, html: true});
    }
    if (x.src == images[1])
    {
        imghtml = '<img src ="b.jpg" width = "150px">'
        $('#popover').popover({placement: 'right', content: imghtml, html: true});
    }
}

function displaypreviousimage(x){
    x.src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DOSczbmX4AAiFEd.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#popover').popover('destroy');
$('#popover').popover({placement: 'right', content: imghtml, html: true});
$('#popover').popover('show');
```

All I had to do was destroy the previous popover :')